# Reading MarkLogic logs from Query Console using XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to read MarkLogic logs (for eg : ErrorLog.txt) from query console using Xquery. I had the below code but the problem is output is not properly formatted. Result is like below

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $hid in xdmp:hosts()
let $h := xdmp:host-name($hid)
return 
xdmp:filesystem-file("file://" || $h || "/" ||xdmp:data-directory($hid) ||"/Logs/ErrorLog.txt")
```

Problem is result is coming as per host basis like first all log of one host is coming and then starting with time 00:00:01 of host 2 and then 00:00:01 of host 3 after running the Xquery.

```
2019-07-02 00:00:35.668 Info: Merging 2 MB from /cams/q06data02/testQA2/Forests/testQA2-2.2/0002b4cd to /cams/q06data02/testQA2/Forests/testQA2-2.2/0002b4ce, timestamp=15620394303480170
    2019-07-02 00:00:36.007 Info: Merged 3 MB at 9 MB/sec to /cams/q06data02/testQA2/Forests/test2-2.2/0002b4ce
    2019-07-02 00:00:38.161 Info: Deleted 3 MB at 399 MB/sec /cams/q06data02/test2/Forests/test2-2.2/0002b4cd
```

Is it possible to get the output with hostname included with log entries and also if we can sort the output by timelines something like

```
host 1 : 2019-07-02 00:00:01 : Info Merging ....
host 2 : 2019-07-02 00:00:02 : Info Deleted 3 MB at 399 MB/sec ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log files are text files. You can parse and sort them like any other text file.
Although they can get very large (GB+), so simple methods may not be performant.
Plus you need to be able to parse the text into fields in order to sort by a field.
Since the first 20 bytes of every line is the time stamp, and that timestamp is in ISO format which sorts lexically same as date, you can split the file by lines and sort using basic colation to get by time sorting of multiple files.

In V9 one can use the pair of [`xdmp:logfile-scan`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:logfile-scan) and `xdmp:logmessage-parse` to efficiently search over log files (remotely as well as local) and then transform the results into text, XML (attribute or element format) or JSON.

One can also use the REST API for the same.
see: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/logs

Once logfiles (ideally a selected subset of log messages that is small enough to manage) is converted to a structured format (xml , json or text lines) then sorting, searching, enriching etc is easily performed.

For something much better take a look at Ops Director https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/opsdir/intro

Comment: REST API https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/logs did the trick for us. Thanks :)